# Change x-axis in pandas histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame with capacity of smartphones

Data example:

| index | capacity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 128 |
| 2 | 64 |
| 3 | 256 |
| 4 | 512 |
| 5 | 64 |
| 6 | 32 |
| ... | ... |

I want to build histogram of this data.

I tried do it using:

```
data.hist(column="capacity", bins=data["capacity"].unique().size, range=(0, max(data["capacity"])), grid=False, edgecolor='black')
plt.show()
```

Histogram shows amount of smartphones in intervals by 100:
[image: what I have]

I want it looks like this:
[image: what I want]

How can I do it?

Comment: With seaborn: `sns.countplot(data=data, x='capacity')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option:

```
df['capacity'].value_counts().plot.bar(rot=0)
```